# Improve performance on multicolumn index and sort

Tags: postgresql, indexing, query-performance, postgresql-performance

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE (col1, col2) IN (($1, $2), ($3, $4))
ORDER  BY col3
LIMIT  10;
```

Output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`:

```
 Limit  (cost=59174.75..59174.77 rows=10 width=113) (actual time=3632.627..3632.661 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=59174.75..59180.22 rows=2188 width=113) (actual time=3632.623..3632.634 rows=10 loops=1)
         Sort Key: col3
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 27kB
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2.62..59127.46 rows=2188 width=113) (actual time=0.234..3561.309 rows=38347 loops=1)
   ...........
   Total runtime: 3632.818 ms
```

But when I remove the order:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE (col1, col2) IN (($1, $2), ($3, $4)) LIMIT 10;
 Limit  (cost=2.62..272.85 rows=10 width=105) (actual time=0.258..1.143 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2.62..59127.46 rows=2188 width=105) (actual time=0.255..1.115 rows=10 loops=1)
........
Total runtime: 1.306 ms
```

1. There is a composite `btree index on (col1, col2)` and a `btree index on col3`.
2. Write performance and storage is not a priority. The read performance is paramount and needs to be as fast as possible.
3. This must be able to support querying with IN clause: `WHERE (col1, col2) IN (($1, $2), ($3, $4)) ORDER BY col3 LIMIT 10;`. (Look ups are always with an IN clause and then order.)

Note: Is it possible to create an index on (col1, col2, col3)? That would look up using `(col1, col2)` and have `col3` already ordered ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You got your answer in the question already.
For the given query, a [multicolumn index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-multicolumn.html) on `(col1, col2, col3)` should be perfect. Just try it.

More about order of columns in a multicolumn B-tree index under this related question on dba.SE:
[Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)

In addition, if you don't actually need all columns from `table1`, only put the required ones in the `SELECT` list instead of `*` to gain performance.

#### IN

As for your added requirement:

```
WHERE (col1, col2) IN (($1, $2), ($3, $4))
```

is equivalent to:

```
WHERE (col1 = $1 AND col2 = $2 OR
       col1 = $3 AND col2 = $4)
```

This reduces the effectiveness of the index over `(col1, col2, col3)`, since Postgres cannot just fetch the pre-sorted list from the index. It depends. The fewer items in your `IN` list and the more rows with the same `col3` per `(col1, col2)` there are, the more you can gain from said index.

You'll have to test. Create the index additionally, be sure your [server is configured reasonably](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization), statistics are up to date ([`ANALYZE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-analyze.html)) and your [cost settings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-CONSTANTS) are reasonable and then `EXPLAIN` will show what Postgres picks. Be sure to run a set of queries that represents your use cases. In the end, remove indexes that don't get used.

#### Trick Postgres into using special index effectively

The sort step seems to be the expensive part. Try this alternative query: one `UNION ALL` leg per item in your `IN` list. This makes an offer to Postgres that it can't refuse: the special index fits the legs of this query perfectly. And the final sort step is cheap for only a few `IN` items.

```
(
SELECT *
FROM   table1
WHERE  col1 = $1 AND col2 = $3
ORDER  BY col3
LIMIT  10
)
UNION  ALL
(
SELECT *
FROM   table1
WHERE  col1 = $3 AND col2 = $4
ORDER  BY col3
LIMIT  10
)
... UNION  ALL ...
ORDER  BY col3
LIMIT  10
```

Note that all parentheses are required to allow `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` for each leg in addition to the final `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.

Comment: @erwinbranstetter, I modified the question slightly: `This must be able to support querying with IN clause: WHERE (col1, col2) IN (($1, $2), ($3, $4)) ORDER BY col3 LIMIT 10;. (Look ups are always with an IN clause and then order.)`

Does the multi-column index approach still hold under this condition?

Comment: @alumns: I added something to address your addition.

Comment: I added the index and look up without the IN clause is very fast. However, when I start using IN clause, the performance degrades rather dramatically. Is there anything else I can do to improve performance?

Comment: It seems that the object is to avoid the expensive `SORT` step. Single look ups manage to avoid it while IN clause didn't

Comment: @alumns: I might have something for you. Check the added paragraph.

Comment: I am happy to report that I have been using this recently and this actually works extremely well. Much better than the IN clause. Although the catch is that if I want to do LIMIT 50 OFFSET 100, I actually need to do LIMIT 150 on each of the UNION ALL sub query. I guess there is no way around this?

Comment: @alumns: I can't think of an easy way. You might get somewhere [with this related answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18300/can-spatial-index-help-a-range-order-by-limit-query/22500#22500), but your case is more complicated with conditions on two different columns.

Comment: Thanks Erwin, I can actually run a migration and change it to a single column. Do you think making a single column condition would help?

Comment: The other difference between the linked case and yours: your IDs are not in a single range, but arbitrary pick from a set. You can still try the approach. It depends on all the details: distribution of values, how many IDs in the WHERE clause, how big are LIMIT / OFFSET, ...

Comment: umm I see. I think I might do this: I will run a migration to compact this multi-column condition into a single column. And then see if there is a performance benefit and if there is still issues. I will write more in depth details in a separate question. Thanks for your help

Comment: @alumns: Two columns are not a problem per se. Just multiplies possible combinations for the linked solution.